# login problem for 13.10, my username does not appear

Tags: login, lightdm, 13.10

After upgrading my Ubuntu to the newest version 13.10, in the login interface, my account does not appear. I can login the guest session. There is also a remote login. I have no place to input my username to login my account. Does anyone have the same problem?

----EDIT----

Here is the file lightdm.conf

[SeatDefaults]

greeter-session=unity-greeter

user-session=ubuntu

----EDIT TWO---

Here is the official bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1235785

Comment: Can you give us the content of `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and add it to [your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/363128/edit)?

Comment: Sure, MadMike, I have updated my post. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Anand Can you login in tty1?

Comment: yes, i can login in tty1 with either my username or root.

Comment: What is your numeric user ID?  By default, the greeter will not show your user entry if your UID is less than 500.  Type 'id' at a shell prompt to see your UID.

Comment: @Mox, my UID is 128. I have changed the lowest UID from 500 to 50. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution that worked for me. Because I had installed likewise-open it had told lightdm to hide local users.

open the following file from command line:

> sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

In the [SeatDefaults] section, there's a line that should say the following:

> greeter-hide-users=false

(mine had gotten changed to true, so all local users weren't being displayed. Rebooted after than and I can see my local users again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem partially solved by login in the tty1 as root and run:

```
 /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --autologin=USERNAME
```

and then

```
reboot
```

See also:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM

Now after reboot, I am in my account. But if I log out, my account still does not appear in the list.